# weighted sum of values VS sum of weighted values,

Tags: expressions

I studied Neural Network, and there occurs following formula.

```
S = Sum ( weight of N * value of N )
```

In the text book and other references, they indicate S as 'an weighted sum of values'.
I have some confusion on it, because it looks like 'Sum' Of 'weighted values', which is exactly the same as the way I read the formula.

Could you let me know what I am missing here?

Thank you,

Comment: I would have written "sum of weighted values".  If "weighted sum of values" is used multiple places to represent that equation it's probably because the term was copied from one place to the other by someone either too lazy to rework it or too unfamiliar with English to question it.  While English can be quite imprecise, it can also be quite precise if used with care.

Comment: @Centaurus How is it not about English? It's about the placement of a modifier in an English phrase.

Comment: Syko, I think you are right. Literally, the values are weighted and then summed, so it should be a 'sum of weighted values'. But it is accepted shorthand to call such a thing a 'weighted sum' (no mention of values, because that is understood). Saying 'a weighted sum of values' is then a pleonasm (it is redundant to mention 'values'; you're not going to sum anything else, it's what sums do. But a pleonasm is not incorrect or ungrammatical and though usually considered undesirable style, can be used for emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, because the formula uses the phrase "weight of N", your proposed phrasing of "sum of weighted values" is perhaps more appropriate. This is because the weight is (apparently, by the phrase "weight of N") an inherent property of the value itself, and not a function of the particular summing operation.

However, in general, the phrase "weighted sum of values" is more commonly used, and is indeed more appropriate, because the weights are not inherent to the values themselves; they are not "weighted values", they are simply values, and the weighting is applied by nature of the summing, not by nature of the values themselves.

In light of this, I think it is more natural (if only by precedent) to use "weighted sum of values", although if you were to write "sum of weighted values" nobody would find it odd.

Comment: I believe that in neural nets, the weights are actually associated with the sums. The weights are first determined by a "learning" process, and then properties of an object are evaluated by plugging the values associated with the object into a formula involving these weighted sums.

Answer (score 1):

In math, a *weighted sum* of variables *x_i* generally means

*S* = Sum_*i* ( *w_i* * *x_i* ).

So the parsing is *(weighted sum) of values,* and not *weighted (sum of values),* which is how you're parsing it.

Comment: But wouldn't 'sum of weighted values' be more logical, and etically expected?

Comment: Conceptually, in a *"weighted sum of values"*, the weights remain the same while the values change. I'm sure that not all uses of *"weighted sum"* behave this way, but many do, and you should consider this as part of the etymology.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact is that natural languages are less precise than structured languages. English is a natural language. Math is a structured language. There are domain specific languages that are precise and sound like English. One of the things that you learn when flying an airplane is how to talk to the tower. I can't tell you how many times my sister told My brother and I to talk english when we were discussing time travel theory. Jargon is a unique blend of structured and natural language that gains in specificity but looses  in communicability outside the group. in math jargon a weighted sum is exactly defined as the formula you give, but the english meaning of the words disagree.

Comment: But Denis below says that 'The weighted sum of values expression stems from statistics and mathematics'; I can't see how this ties in with your 'Math is a structured language. There are domain specific languages that are precise and sound like English'.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I understood that "sum of weighted values" meant a "weighted sum of values", but the former didn't it ring quite right to me.

The reason is, "sum of weighted values" seemed inconsistent with other expressions used in mathematics and statistics: weighted average, weighted arithmetic mean, weighted geometric mean, weighted harmonic mean, and so forth.

Comment: But hildred above says that 'Math is a structured language. There are domain specific languages that are precise and sound like English'; I can't see how this ties in with your 'The weighted sum of values expression stems from statistics and mathematics'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: what I meant is hopefully clearer now? To me, the meat of hildred's answer is in its first three sentences and in the very last one. He could have stripped everything in between to get the point across a lot better.

Comment: So patterns are more important than logic in mathsspeak?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Wouldn't that seem logical? Math speak is natural language.

Comment: hildred is obviously speaking about mathsspeak (the terminology) rather than the 'language of mathematics' when he mentions precision ('sound like English'). If an unusual but grammatical phrase more logically applies to a situation than an alternative candidate that would conform to the pattern of other expressions in the same neck of the woods, I'd expect mathematicians to choose the less idiom-like but more logical variant. But then, they can't even agree on a definition of 'function'.